# html5 folding shapes

Tags: html, html5-canvas

is there a way to create folding shapes in html-5's 2d context? i'm trying to create an effect similar to this: http://youtu.be/-GowlLiZqbg

Comment: It might be helpful to use Three.js with <canvas> backend: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Comment: but wouldn't that mean that it would be 3d instead of 2d? and as i understand it not every browser supports webGL(except chrome which executes perfectly, with firefox in second place)

Comment: If you read the link above carefully it states that there is 2D <canvas> backend for rendering 3D animations.